# Nav won't change size upon scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I found this jquery code to make my nav change its size when a user begins to scroll. It doesn't appear to be working, though...

```
$(function(){
    $('.nav').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var $nav = $('.nav');
    if ($('body').scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') {
            $nav.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                height:'60px'
            }, 600);
        }
    } else {
        if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
            $nav.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                height:'40px'
            }, 600);
        }  
    }
```

Here is all the code:
http://codepen.io/DerekDev/pen/Bydgpz

So if any of you have a solution, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
    var nav = $('.nav');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 0) {
      if(!nav.hasClass("smallNav")) {
        nav.hide();
        nav.removeClass('bigNav').addClass("smallNav").fadeIn( "slow");
      }
    } else {
      if(!nav.hasClass("bigNav")) {
        nav.hide();
        nav.removeClass("sml-logo").addClass('bigNav').fadeIn( "slow");
      }
    }

  });
});
```

and CSS rules:

```
.bigNav{
height:60px;
}
.smallNav{
height:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you want to check the `window` scrollTop, not the `body`

Secondly, you want to change the height of the UL, not the `.nav` element, and you seem to have the order mixed up, you probably want `40px` when it's small, and `60px` when it's big !

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var $nav = $('.nav');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
      console.log($nav.data('size'))
        if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') {
            $nav.data('size','small').find('ul').stop().animate({
                height:'40px'
            }, 600);
        }
    } else {
        if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
            $nav.data('size','big').find('ul').stop().animate({
                height:'60px'
            }, 600);
        }  
    }
});
```

[**PEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEzPWe)